# Multiple Calendars with different timings

Tags: controls

I am looking for some help on scheduling, how to setup multiple calendars in different timings.
My Scenario:
 one job has to run in multiple times
1. calendar 1 - has to run at 10:00AM

2. Calendar 2 has to run at 4:00 PM
3. Calenar 3 has to run at 11:00 PM

Please let me know how to setup this in Control M?
 Can we setup time for each calendar?

Thanks in advance
Ed

Answer (score 0):

1. if Calendar means different schedule period , eg,

Calendar1 has JAN,FEB
Calendar2 has MARCH, APRIL
CALENDAR3 has MAY,June

then you need to setup three jobs bind to each calendar with respect to its time for period.

2. If Job need to run multiple time in a day you can use **cyclic option** and c*yclic interval* can be set to **Specific Time** ,

make sure you select Tolerance to 2-5 min to avoid job skip at that time .

Please comment your reply if you are looking for something else .

Thanks,
Chandramani

Comment: Thanks Chandramani, My question was calendar1 has to run on Monday at 10 AM, calendar 2 has to run on Wednesday at 4 PM and calendar3 has to run at Friday at 11 PM and I want to add all these for same particular job. Different calendars with different timings. please suggest me.